# Setting transparency on extent indicator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, layouts, extent-indicators

When creating an extent indicator in ArcMap 10.3, is it possible to set the transparency of the background colour of the extent indicator frame? I want the extent rectangle to have a colour fill, but not a solid colour as below:

[image: example]

In the frame properties dialogue box, I only seem to have the option to select a solid colour:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using the default extent indicator in ArcMap, I don't think you can set transparency on the outline or the fill.

However, if you have ArcMap, you should also have access to ArcGIS Pro.  The extent indicator in ArcGIS Pro does allow you to have more options with the styling including setting the transparency of the [extent indicator](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/extent-indicators.htm) outline and fill.

[image]

Comment: Saw this post on geonet where they use a picture marker symbol as a workaround for ArcMap.  Not ideal, but thought id share https://geonet.esri.com/thread/44698

Comment: Unfortunately don't have access to ArcGIS Pro, but seems the workaround may be the only solution in ArcMap. Cheers